# Updating individual table from two joined tables (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

A friend of mine just asked me this question and I'm not sure of the answer.

Is it possible to update an individual table that was added to another table using JOIN?

For example, we have `P.table_a` and `P.table_b`. `table_a` and `table_b` were "joined". Can I update `table_a` from the returned (joined) result, and have the original `table_a` reflect this change? Or does the join make a copy of the tables, so that any edits only affect the result of the JOIN? I'm leaning towards the first option, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: This highly depends on the DBMS. Which one are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I believe they use MySQL (I think that's a DBMS...)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear.  But the general answer is "yes".  Here are some mechanisms:

- Many databases support `join` directly in the `update` syntax.  In that case, you can just write the `update` with an explicit `join`.
- Many databases support the `merge` statement.  In that case, the `merge` acts a lot like an `update` and allows `join`s.
- Many databases support triggers on views.  In that case, you can write an update trigger on a view.  When it is executed, then the trigger can update the view.
- Some databases support materialized views.  These are views (which can have joined tables).  When underlying data changes, then the materialized view will change.

There are probably additional methods that I've left out.  No doubt, any database you are using supports at least one of these.

EDIT:

Once again, I don't know what you mean.  The only formal use I can think of for "virtual table" is a specific mechanism in SQLite to refer to external data sources.

Perhaps all you really want is a view.  This is standard and available in basically all databases.  The view definition can have joins in it.  When the view is executed, the results come from the most recent versions of the underlying tables.  There is no "update" involved; the query that defines the view is executed (in some fashion) when the query referencing it is executed.

Comment: This is a great answer, considering how vague my question is. I realize it's very unclear, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it clearer. Suppose virtual table_c is table_a joined with table_b. If I edit table_c, will the changes be reflected in table_a and/or table_b? I'm reading through your answer and I'm still a bit iffy on some of the terminology (SQL is still quite new to me). It may be that I'm using the wrong terminology as well. I can't quite tell if you answered the question I'm actually thinking about or not. I don't know if I expressed it correctly. Does this make sense?

Comment: I just meant "virtual table" meaning the resulting table. Didn't mean to throw false terminology at you. Turns out that he's actually building these queries in Java, which I was not aware of. I think that accounts for the lack of clarity--I didn't quite understand what he was asking because he left that out of his initial question. I do apologize for the confusion--i'm still giving you a +1 on this because it is a very informative answer!